# hot network questions have inconsistent CSS for visited/not visited depending on the site you're on

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, design, hot-questions, sidebar

This is a HNQ excerpt from Stack Overflow. Visited questions are objectively darker.

[image]

This is a HNQ excerpt from Super User. Visited questions are objectively lighter.

[image]

This is a HNQ excerpt from Seasoned Advice. Visited questions are objectively darker.

[image]

This is a HNQ excerpt from Puzzling, a beta site. Visited questions are objectively darker, although the difference is hard to spot.

[image]

This is a HNQ excerpt from Travel. Visited questions actually have a completely different color.

[image]

These are 5 different sites, with 5 different formats for how the HNQ sidebar displays links. Some make visited links darker. Some make them lighter. Some make them a little big darker. some give visited links a completely different color. This is very confusing: If someone visits one of these HNQ questions and wants to continue browsing the HNQ from there, they likely expect that the links in that HNQ segment have consistent layout compared to the HNQ segment from the website they came from.

Is this something worth looking into? I realize that each site has their own look and feel, but an element that appears on every site should be consistent IMHO. People have expectations about how links work, and one of those is that if you click on a link within the same domain (which the HNQ segment arguably is), they behave similary on that page as they do on the page you come from.

Comment: Thanks for submitting this request. We do want to standardize how things like this are done across communities. We'll add it to the list of things to look into.

Comment: @Hynes Do you have any updates about this so far?

Comment: @Hynes year and half later, any updates? "No, we won't do this" is also better than leaving this hanging out in the air, IMO.

Comment: I believe at some point the styles for the Information Security and Cryptography sites were changed to eliminate the visited/not visited distinction.  Does that count as an "update"?

Comment: Related questions on MSO: [Dark mode contrast: regular text has much higher contrast than `--theme-post-title-color`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420204/11107541) and [Please swap (or change) the styling colors of visited and non-visited links in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396792/11107541).